# Cannot connect MySQL and PowerBI using odbc connector

Tags: powerbi, mysql-connector

I cannot connect PowerBI and MySQL. I have installed MySQL net connector 8.1.0 64-bit and MySQL connector odbc 8.1.0 64-bit. I have Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable 2015-2022 x- 64. I use MySQL workbench (Ver 8.0.34 for Win64 on x86_64) and the latest version of Power BI (Version: 2.120.963.0 64-bit (August, 2023)).

When I am trying to connect the error message pops up that I need to have one or more additional components and the 'learn more' in the error message takes me to the link of net connector which I have already downloaded. Is there any other way to import SQL file to PowerBI?

Please suggest me how to proceed.

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL Server if you RDBMS is MySQL?

Comment: I think OP means MySQL server?

Comment: Please do not spam the tags with irrelevant tags! Tgis question has nothing to do with mysql workbench or mysql server. Also, please avoid asking questions that are not programming or software development related. Please ask this question on MS support forum.